# Select k random rows from postgres django ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

We have a requirement, that  we want to select k random rows from a database.
So, our intial thought was going like this :-

```
table.objects.filter(..).order_by('?')[:k]
```

but then we read over the internet that this is highly inefficient solution so we came up with this (not so innovative):-

```
random.sample(table.objects.filter(..), k)
```

But this seems to be more slower than previous.

So, we want to know what is correct approach for selection exactly *k* rows from the database, which in our case is postgres.

Comment: making [:k] is a good approach, because it automatically set's the LIMIT in your SQL.

Comment: `order_by('?')` is really slow for big tables. It is faster to fetch `max_id`, then choose `k` numbers from the set `1, ..., max_id` in the Python code.

Comment: The second one is less efficient because you are fetching all matching rows, rather than just the k that you need.

Comment: @Tobias you need fetch `max_id` and then do sample k ids out of set(range(1,max_id)) and then do
filter(id__in = k_sampled_ids) ?

Comment: Also for big tables you would prefer 1st or second?

Comment: @TarunGarg Yes, exactly. That's how we solved precisely this kind of problem. Not sure what you mean by "also for big tables would prefer 1st or second"?

Comment: @Tobias if you are to given a choice between 1st and 2nd your selection would be ?

Also people say that order_by('?') copies whole table in memory, i want to know whether it copies whole table OR the table after limiting values.

Comment: If I *had* to choose, I'd choose the first option, since the second option fetches the entire set of objects (if I understand your notation correctly) and this will inevitable use much more memory than your db doing this for you.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Roseman mentioned in a comment, the reason why

```
random.sample(table.objects.filter(..), k)
```

is slow, is because you'd have to fetch *all* objects, then find `k` out of that query set.

I have encountered exactly the same type of problem and the way we solved this was to

- Find `max_id` in the table.
- Pick `k` numbers from the set of `1, ..., max_id`
- Do `table.objects.filter(id__in=set_of_ks)`

This of course assumes that there are no "holes" in the set of table IDs.

Comment: But it executes two queries, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but fetching `max_id` should be done at constant time so it is (very) fast. Next query is exactly the rows that you want which you will have to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know roughly the size of your table you can use the new [TABLESAMPLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) clause to select a percentage of the rows at random. Then, you can always LIMIT it afterwards.

A short blog article covering it [here](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/).